# Is there an RPG Dialogue plugin available for the Unity Game Engine?

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine

Is there an RPG Dialogue plugin available for the Unity Game Engine? Or maybe an RPG starter kit? My Unity game needs a dialogue engine of some kind. I'd rather not have to make it from scratch if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a RPG kit in development which will feature everything you need for a RPG ...

More infos:
http://gamingislove.blogspot.com/

Comment: Thanks! That's what i was looking for. I wonder how long I'll have to wait for that to be done. Oh well. I have many other things to be working on for my game in the mean time.

Comment: This is now called Okashi RPG Script, and be bought right away http://rpg-kit.com/system.html

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://ninjaportal.com/NinjaPortal/UDE.html

Dunno if it is good enough but it should be enough to get you started :)

Comment: This looks great. The price is only $100, and it looks to be exactly what I'm looking for in terms of dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

just to inform you:
The RPG Kit has been released yesterday - it's called ORK, short for Okashi RPG Kit, you can find it at [rpg-kit.com](http://rpg-kit.com)

Comment: Thanks a ton for letting me know! This toolset looks awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll throw this out there. Dialoguer is a pretty easy to use, easy to implement dialogue system for Unity:

- [Asset Store Link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/14854)
- [Official Website](http://www.dialoguer.info/)

It lets you make dialogue trees with a node based editor

Comment: Some more links:

[Screenshots and GIFs](http://imgur.com/a/YwxTF), [Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvELH4QqPDg&list=PLvUbtOaq6zypgTb0raLhSgpUQVdbmuX-y&index=1)

Answer (score 0):

I am an author of this extension for Unity, it's called Dialogical:

http://u3d.as/kY0

It is not RPG specific, but it would fulfil all the needs of a complex dialogue tree you'd need in an RPG. It uses events to plug into your code, so that it can interact with any part of your game.

Features and screenshots:
http://www.ennoble-studios.com/games/dialogical-unity-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fungus](http://fungusgames.com/). It's a free open source plug in and it is also available on unity asset store.